# MS Word VBA: I need a color palette dialog box

Tags: vba, ms-word, dialog, color-picker, word-2010

In VBA for MS Word 2010, how can I get Word to bring up a color palette dialog box so the user can pick a color?

[image]

There are tons of examples on how to do it in Excel, but I haven't found any help for Word users. Here's the code for Excel:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPatterns).Show
```

Problem is, there's no wdDialogPatterns equivalent, nor can I find anything with a name that suggests a color palette dialog. I've found wdFormatBordersAndShading, but it's not quite the same: I want the user to select a color for later and repeated use.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, any approach that works in Excel can also work in Word. Please provide information about how you do it in Excel using the EDIT link below your question.

Comment: Thanks. Did that above.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know Word does not have the same option as in Excel.
Instead you can call a Windows inbuilt solution via .dll.
I have recently created one in order to be able to pick more colors as text background color.

Fisrtly the Windows documentation where you can see all the options you can modify:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646830(v=vs.85).aspx
Hint: CC_ANYCOLOR = 0x00000100 = &H100 (You need to use this form in VBA)

From my code example you can see how to implement it:
This goes top of Module:

```
Private Type CHOOSECOLORSTRUCT
   lStructSize     As Long
   hwndOwner       As Long
   hInstance       As Long
   rgbResult       As Long
   lpCustColors    As Long
   flags           As Long
   lCustData       As Long
   lpfnHook        As Long
   lpTemplateName  As String
End Type

Private Declare Function ChooseColor Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
   Alias "ChooseColorA" _
  (lpcc As CHOOSECOLORSTRUCT) As Long
```

This is the picker caller function with optionally submitted OriginalColor:

```
Public Function PickColor(Optional OriginalColor As Variant = 8421376) 'You can define any colour as default instead of 8421376)
    Dim cc As CHOOSECOLORSTRUCT
    Dim dwCustClrs(0 To 15) As Long

    With cc
        .Flags = &H100 Or &H1 Or &H2
        .lStructSize = Len(cc)
        .hwndOwner = 0
        .lpCustColors = VarPtr(dwCustClrs(0))
        .rgbResult = OriginalColor
    End With

    If CHOOSECOLOR(cc) = 1 Then
        PickColor = cc.rgbResult
    End If
End Function
```

And finally this is how you call it in action:

```
Sub F_HáttérSzínVálasztó()
    With Selection.Font.Shading
        .BackgroundPatternColor = PickColor(Selection.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to use this solution with Access 2016 (32 bit) when the old [Access 97 sample](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0060.htm) from Terry Kreft did not.  In a simplified manner it can be used like this:   `txtCtl.Properties("BackColor") = PickColor(Me.txtCtl.Properties("BackColor"))`

Answer (score 4):

On x64 Word you must modify Ádám's code below as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Type CHOOSECOLOR
  lStructSize As LongLong
  hwndOwner As LongPtr
  hInstance As LongPtr
  rgbResult As LongLong
  lpCustColors As LongPtr
  flags As LongLong
  lCustData As LongLong
  lpfnHook As LongLong
  lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function MyChooseColor _
    Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorW" _
    (ByRef pChoosecolor As CHOOSECOLOR) As Boolean

Public Function GetColor(ByRef col As LongLong) As _
    Boolean

  Static CS As CHOOSECOLOR
  Static CustColor(15) As LongLong

  CS.lStructSize = Len(CS)
  CS.hwndOwner = 0
  CS.flags = &H1 Or &H2
  CS.lpCustColors = VarPtr(CustColor(0))
  CS.rgbResult = col
  CS.hInstance = 0
  GetColor = MyChooseColor(CS)
  If GetColor = False Then Exit Function

  GetColor = True
  col = CS.rgbResult
End Function
```

Use the function for example with the `TextColor` property of a `Font` object:

```
Sub FontColorTest()
  Dim col As LongLong
  col = rgb(200, 100, 50)
  GetColor col
  Dim p As Word.Paragraph
  Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)
  p.Range.Font.TextColor.rgb = CLng(col)
End Sub
```

Please note, that the `GetColor` function requires a parameter of type `LongLong` whereas the `TextColor.rgb` property is of type `Long`.

Comment: Somehow if I want to select a color from the continuum on the right, I have to click on a basic color on the left first.