# Colour palette not coming even after firing the code in 64bit Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, colors, 64-bit, powerpoint, palette

I have used the color picker code from here:
[Show color picker for user to choose from in VBA powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514563/show-color-picker-for-user-to-choose-from-in-vba-powerpoint)

This code is working well in Powerpoint 32 bit vba. But it does not work in 64 bit, MS365. I modified it using Ptrsafe and also changing few long to longptr. But still the colour palette does not appear when I am running the code.

Please help me.

Comment: I am working on Windows 10 64 Bit and Office 365 32 Bit and the code is working well.

Comment: Please restructure your question to show the code you are trying to use for your 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ChooseColor_Dlg Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "ChooseColorA" (pcc As CHOOSECOLOR_TYPE) As LongPtr

Private Type CHOOSECOLOR_TYPE
lStructSize As LongPtr
hwndOwner As LongPtr
hInstance As LongPtr
rgbResult As LongPtr
lpCustColors As LongPtr
flags As LongPtr
lCustData As LongPtr
lpfnHook As LongPtr
lpTemplateName As String
End Type
```

And

```
Static BDF(16) As LongPtr
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I shall try this.