# Use the Default Background Color Picker Popup menu

Tags: vba, ms-access, popup, color-picker

Summary:
I'm trying to make a custom popup menu with some options, amongst which i would like to insert the default background color picker from the Text Formatting tab. With this, i would love if i could know which color code has been picked so i can set it as a background color for a textbox.

What i have tried:

```
Sub Make_Popup_CuloriForm()

'Add PopUp menu
With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
                                MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    
With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .Caption = "Actualizeaza formular"
    .OnAction = "fCuloriForm"
    .Parameter = "1"
    .FaceId = 159
    .BeginGroup = True
End With

 With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .Caption = "Elimina formular"
    .OnAction = "fCuloriForm"
    .Parameter = "2"
    .FaceId = 330
    .BeginGroup = True
End With

End With

' Application.CommandBars.Add c(36)
End Sub
```

What i need is to add another control to the popup menu, but that should be the builtin color picker.

thank you

LE:
This is what i need:
[image: like this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show color picker for user to choose from in VBA powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514563/show-color-picker-for-user-to-choose-from-in-vba-powerpoint)

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514563/show-color-picker-for-user-to-choose-from-in-vba-powerpoint. Whether or not that can be attached to a button on a custom menu is beyond me.

Comment: thank you both, but that's not what i need.